# In Scheme, how to compare two arguments and return false if one isn't given

Tags: list, comparison, scheme, racket

I feel so damp in not being able to make this work. 
All I need to do is to make it so if one argument is missing, the output should show `false`, for example, `(my-list '(7 6) p) false` or `#f`. So far I tried the following with `null?`

`(define (my-list list1 list2)
  (if (null? list2) 
      false`

And the other with `list?`

`(define (my-list list1 list2)
  (if (list? list1) 
      false`

NOTE: I have other comparison and these two contradict with my other conditions and won't work if I have either of `list?` or `null?`. What's the most effective way to make this work? Thanks much!

Comment: It won't work if `list?` evaluates to true?

Comment: It's still not entirely clear what you want. In particular, you write `(my-list '(7 6) p)` ... but this expression depends on what value `p` is bound to. You need to be more precise about what you mean by `missing`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(define (longer-list list1 list2)
  ; use `or` to check if either condition is true
  (if (or (not (list? list1)) (not (list? list2)))
      false
      <do something else here>))
```

Explanation: just check *both* arguments to see if either one is *not* a list and return `false` if that's the case. Otherwise, just do whatever you want to do in the "else" part of the conditional expression. I don't think it's necessary to check if either argument is `null?`, if they're lists their size will be zero, so it's fine to call `length` on them.

Comment: Lopez I knew this logic but didn't know how the correct syntax to code in Scheme. Thanks much, your explanation is very helpful.

Comment: `(not (and (list? list1) (list? list2)))` would read better: Are not both of the arguments lists?

Comment: My pleasure! also take into account @DanD.'s comment, he simplified the condition using De Morgan's law - it might be more readable for some, but I prefer my answer as it is :)